# my filtering options doesn't work but in the first page

Tags: asp.net-mvc, actionlink, pagedlist

I've written some ActionLinks to filter the data on a movieshop base on genre while using PagedList.Mvc for paging.

The problem is that the ActionLinks work properly,but only filter the movies existing on the first page. What can I do?

View:

```
@using PagedList.Mvc
@using Shop.CustomHtmlHelpers
@using Shop.Domain.Entities
@model PagedList.IPagedList<Shop.Domain.Entities.Movie>

@{
ViewBag.Title = "MovieDisplay";
}

<h2>MovieDisplay</h2>

@using (@Html.BeginForm("MovieDisplay", "Movies", FormMethod.Get))
{
<div class="container">

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-10">

            @foreach (Product p in Model)
            {
                var item = (Movie)p;

                <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
                    <div class="tile">
                        <br />
                        <b>@item.Title</b>
                        <br />
                        @item.Year
                        <br/>
                        @item.Genre
                        <br/>
                        @item.Director.Name
                        @Html.Image(@item.Image,"200")
                        <br />
                        $ @item.Price
                        <br/>
                        <br />
                        <button onclick="location.href = '@Url.Action("AddtoCart", "ShoppingCart", new {id = p.Id})'" type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-su btn-sm ">
                            <span> <i class="fa fa-shopping-basket" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>  AddtoCart
                        </button>
                        <br />
                        <br /><br />
                    </div>
                </div>
            }
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
}
@Html.ActionLink("Horror", "MovieDisplay", new { Genre = "Horror" } )
@Html.ActionLink("Action", "MovieDisplay", new { Genre = "Action" })
@Html.ActionLink("Drama", "MovieDisplay", new { Genre = "Drama" })
@Html.ActionLink("Animation", "MovieDisplay", new { Genre = "Animation" })
@Html.ActionLink("Comedy", "MovieDisplay", new { Genre = "Comedy" })
@Html.ActionLink("Crime", "MovieDisplay", new { Genre = "Crime" })
@Html.ActionLink("Sci-Fi", "MovieDisplay", new { Genre = "Sci-Fi" })
@Html.ActionLink("Fantasy", "MovieDisplay", new { Genre = "Fantasy" })
@Html.ActionLink("Historical", "MovieDisplay", new { Genre = "Historical" })
@Html.ActionLink("Musical", "MovieDisplay", new { Genre = "Musical" })

@Html.PagedListPager(Model, page => Url.Action("MovieDisplay", new { page, searchTerm = Request.QueryString["searchTerm"], Genre = "Genre" }))
```

Related ActionResult:

```
public ActionResult MovieDisplay(string searchTerm, int? page , string genre)
{
    MediaContext mc = new MediaContext();

    var movies = mc.Movies.ToList().ToPagedList(page ?? 1, 6);

    if(genre !=null)
        movies = movies.Where(m => m.Genre == genre).ToList().ToPagedList(page ?? 1, 6);

    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchTerm))
    { }

    else
        movies = mc.Movies.Where(x => x.Title.Contains(searchTerm)).ToList().ToPagedList(page ?? 1, 6);

    return View(movies);
}
```

Comment: Could you put here rendered html result?

Comment: http://www.axgig.com/images/28582025233456664695.png

Comment: http://www.axgig.com/images/98063599737773444400.png

Comment: http://www.axgig.com/images/59952113026528437535.png

Comment: As you see the horror filter didn't bring up the other horror movie which is on the seond page

Comment: debug it, I think in the next page request your filtering options such as genre and searchTerm doesn't resent properly.

Comment: Because you never pass the `page` to the method, so its `null` and your code sets it to 1 (and using `ToList()` means your materializing your whole collection and defeats the one of the main benefits pf paging)

Answer (score 0):

The problem was nothing but a silly mistake I made in the ActionResult :

```
movies = movies.Where(m => m.Genre == genre).ToList().ToPagedList(page ?? 1, 6);
```

Here I actually filter the existing movies ! I should have added the whole movies to the list just like I did for the searchTerm  (that's why the search worked properly for all the pages)

```
 movies = mc.Movies.Where(m => m.Genre == genre).ToList().ToPagedList(page ?? 1, 6);
```